# Derivation of unbiased MLE for Gaussian variance

Tags: machine-learning, unbiased-estimator

I'm currently studying ML basics with the book *Introduction to Machine Learning (Ethem Alpaydin)* and had a question regarding checking whether the maximum likelihood estimators (MLE's) for a Gaussian distribution's parameters are biased or not.

We know that the MLE's for the mean $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$ are each:

$$
\begin{align}
m & = \frac{\sum_t x^t}{N} \\
s^2 & = \frac{\sum_t (x^t - m)^2}{N}
\end{align}
$$

for samples $\mathcal{X} = \left\{ x^t \right\}_{t=1}^N$.

We can check whether these estimators are biased or not by taking their expectations and seeing whether they equal the true values. This is easily verifiable for $m$, but what I'm having trouble understanding is how the author goes about explaining the case for $s^2$. More specifically:

$$
\begin{align}
s^2 & = \frac{\sum_t (x^t - m)^2}{N} = \frac{\sum_t (x^t)^2 - Nm^2}{N} \\
\mathbb{E}[s^2] & = \frac{\sum_t \mathbb{E}[(x^2)^2] - N \mathbb{E}[m^2]}{N} \\
& = \dfrac{N(\sigma^2 + \mu^2) - N\left(\dfrac{\sigma^2}{N} + \mu^2\right)}{N} \\
& = \left( \dfrac{N - 1}{N} \right)\sigma^2 \ne \sigma^2
\end{align}
$$

What's confusing me is the first line. How does $\sum_t (x^t - m)^2 = \sum_t (x^t)^2 - Nm^2$? Please correct me if I'm mistaken, but I believe that:

$$
\begin{align}
\sum_t (x^t - m)^2 & = \sum_t ((x^t)^2 - 2mx^t + m^2) \\
& = \sum_t (x^t)^2 -2m\sum_t x^t + Nm^2
\end{align}
$$
Not only is the sign for $Nm^2$ opposite, but I'm also wondering what happened to the second term $-2m\sum_t x^t$.

If someone could point out where I went wrong or explain why such a difference occurs that'd be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\sum_t x^t= Nm$, the middle term is $-2Nm^2$. It combines with the last term to give $-Nm^2$.